# Typing a generic type but not its own type in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I need to type method signature so it accepts 2 equally typed parameters of different particular concrete subtypes.

Is it possible to code something like this with generics? How would you solve it? (The case is absolutely an example)

```
public <T extends List<?>> T<String> sum(T<Integer> sublistOfInts, T<Boolean> sublistOfBooleans){
     /*fusion both lists*/ 
     return sublistOfStrings;
}
```

EDIT: In the end, what I am looking for is a way for the compiler to pass:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = sum(new ArrayList<Integer>(), new ArrayList<Boolean>());
```

but not:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = sum(new ArrayList<Double>(), new ArrayList<Boolean>());
```

nor

```
ArrayList<String> myList = sum(new LinkedList<Integer>(), new ArrayList<Boolean>());

(...)
```

EDIT 2: I found a better example. Imagine an interface Tuple, with child classes Duple, Triple>..., it would be perfectly nice to have something like

```
<T extends Tuple<?>>  T<String> reset( T<String> input, T<Boolean> listToNull){          
                  T copy = input.copy();
                  for (int i=0; i<input.size();i++){
                       if (listToNull.get(i)){
                             copy.set(i,null);
                       }
                  }  
 }
```

Comment: I don't think I got your question. What do you mean by 2 *equally typed parameters*? And why is return type `T<String>`?

Comment: @Rohit Jain Return type is `T<String>` because he is mistakenly expecting that to be a `List<String>` based on the generic method definition.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Still not clear. I meant to ask, what's the relation between return type and method parameters?

Comment: @Whimusical based on your edit why do you want to be so restrictive on the implementation of the `List` being passed to and returned by your methods? If this was a method in a library I would be very upset to see your first example works and not the third. Looks like Generics is useless the way you want it and you might as well write your method as `public ArrayList<String> sum(ArrayList<Integer> intList, ArrayList<Boolean> boolList){...}`

Comment: @Whimusical: It would be better if you also explain why you expect those result? Why should `ArrayList<Integer>` be fine, but not `ArrayList<Double>`? `Integer` and `Double` have same super type.

Comment: I'd like to create something like the method signature I described, it should be T extends List<?> but T with concrete inner type for each parameter and the result. String, Integer and Boolean are arbitraries for the example.

Comment: I hate when people ask "why do you want to do that?" instead of giving an answer, but in this case, a) you can't make use of methods specific to subtypes inside your `sum` method, and b) you can't parameterize a type argument anyway, so I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Exactly, I am asking an strategy to make as if it would be possible to parametrize type argument. Perhaps there is no equivalent fine way for it in Java.

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to address the idea of supplying type arguments on type arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What I suggest you do instead

First, get rid of the method argument generics. There's no reason to force a caller to provide `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<Boolean>` when you want to return an `ArrayList<String>`. Just accept any `List<Integer>` and `List<Boolean>`, and leave it to your method to turn them into the appropriate return `List`.

Since you know that you want to return some sort of `List` of `String` you can write your parameter as `<T extends List<String>>` and your return type as simply `T`.

That leaves us with the hard part: getting your method to *instantiate* an object of unknown type. That's hard. You can't just do `new T();`. You need to invoke something that will produce a `T` on your behalf. Luckily, Java 8 provides a Functional Interface for `Supplier<T>`. You just need to invoke the `get()` method to get your `ArrayList<String>` or whatever else you might want. The part that's painful is that your invoker needs to provide their own `Supplier`. But I think that's as good as it gets in Java 8.

Here's the code:

```
public <T extends List<String>> T sum(
        List<Integer> sublistOfInts,
        List<Boolean> sublistOfBooleans,
        Supplier<T> listMaker) {
    T sublistOfStrings = listMaker.get();
    /*fusion of both lists*/ 

    return sublistOfStrings;
}
```

At least this compiles:

```
ArrayList<String> myNewList = thing.<ArrayList<String>>sum(intList, boolList, ArrayList::new);
```

And this does not:

```
ArrayList<String> myNewList = thing.<ArrayList<String>>sum(intList, boolList, LinkedListList::new);
```

You can even leave off the type parameter on the invocation. This compiles:

```
ArrayList<String> myNewList = thing.sum(intList, boolList, ArrayList::new);
```

And this does not:

```
ArrayList<String> myNewList = thing.sum(intList, boolList, LinkedListList::new);
```

## Why you can't just do what you're asking

In brief, it's because type arguments can't themselves be parameterized. And that's because we don't know how many type arguments they themselves would take, nor the restrictions that might be placed on them.

Take the relatively obscure class `RoleList`. It extends `ArrayList<Object>`, so it fits `List<?>`. But it doesn't take a type argument at all. So if someone invoked your `sum()` method with `RoleList`, that would require in your example:

```
RoleList<Integer> intList = // something
RoleList<Boolean> boolList = // something
RoleList<String> myNewList = thing.sum(intList, boolList);
```

That clearly can't work since it requires an unparameterized type to take type arguments. And if you took off the type arguments like so:

```
RoleList intList = // something
RoleList boolList = // something
RoleList myNewList = thing.sum(intList, boolList);
```

Then your method needs to be able to accept two `List<Object>` arguments and return a value of `List<Object>`. And that violates your basic premise, that you be able to control such things.

In reality, `RoleList` should not be allowed here at all, because you can't ever guarantee that one instance will contain only `Integer`s, another only `Boolean`s, and a third only `String`s. A compiler that allowed `RoleList` here would necessarily have weaker type checking than we have now.

So the bottom line is that you just can't do what you're asking because Java just isn't built that way.

## Why that's ok

You can still get complete type safety inside your `sum()` method using my suggested method, above. You make sure that the incoming `List`s contain only `Integer` or `Boolean` values, respectively. You make sure that the caller can rely on the return of a specific subtype of `List` containing only `String` values. All of the guarantees that make a difference are there.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that strike me about the above.  How are you instantiating `sublistOfStrings`, and what advantages do you expect to get above using plain old inheritance?

There are a couple of ways of instantiating `T<String>`.  You could have a factory check the class of your arguments, and instantiate it based on that.  Or you could do something like:

```
(List<String>)sublistOfInts.getClass().newInstance()
```

But you can't just go `new T<String>()`.  So you're basing the implementation of your return type off of the type of one of your arguments anyway (unless there's a way I haven't thought of).

By specifying both arguments are of type 'T' doesn't mean they're exactly of the same concrete type 'T' either.  For instance

```
sum((int)1, (long)2L); // valid
sum((int)2, (double)2.0D); // valid ... etc

public <T extends Number> T sum(T a, T b) {
    return a;
}
```

So you aren't enforcing that `sublistOfInts` and `sublistOfBooleans` are both of type say `ArrayList`, and therefore you can return an `ArrayList`.  You still need to write code to check what type of `List<?>` you'll want to return based on the arguments.

I think you're better off not using generics, and using something like this:

```
public List<String> sum(List<Integer> sublistOfInts, List<Boolean> sublistOfBooleans) {
    // Determine what subclass of list you want to instantiate based on `sublistOfInts` and `sublistOfBools`
    // Call factory method or newInstance to instantiate it.
    // Sum, and return.
}
```

You can still call it with subtypes of `List<?>`.  I don't beleive there's any advantage you could get from generics even if Java did let you do it (which is doesn't, because it can't parameterize `T` like that).

Answer (score 0):

I know what you have is just an example but if you only want to return a single list that contains the String value of all the contents in a group of other lists you could just specify a method that takes a varargs of unbounded lists.

```
public List<String> sum(List<?>... lists) {
    List<String> sublistOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(List<?> list : lists) {
        for(Object obj : list) {
            sublistOfStrings.add(obj.toString());
        }
    }

    return sublistOfStrings;
}
```